# A pattern of periodic continued fraction

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, continued-fractions, lucas-numbers

I am interested in the continued fractions which $1$s are consecutive appears.
For example, it is the following values.

$$
\sqrt{7} = [2;\overline{1,1,1,4}] \\
\sqrt{13} = [3;\overline{1,1,1,1,6}]
$$
In this article, let us denote n consecutive $1$s as $1_n$.
Applying this, the above numbers would be as follows.

$$
\sqrt{7} = [2;\overline{1_3,4}] \\
\sqrt{13} = [3;\overline{1_4,6}]
$$

While investigating these numbers, the following pattern was found experimentally.

$$ \sqrt{F(n)^2m^2-(F(n)^2-L(n))m+\frac{(F(n)-1)(F(n)-3)}{4}-\frac{F(n-3)-1}{2}}
=\left[F(n)m-\frac{F(n)-1}{2};\ \overline{1_{n-1},\ 2\left(F(n)m-\frac{F(n)-1}{2}\right)}\right] $$ ($m,n \in \mathbb{N},\ n\equiv\pm1\ (mod3),\ n > 3,\ $$F(n)$ is [Fibonacci number](https://oeis.org/A000045), $L(n)$ is [Lucas number](https://oeis.org/A000032))

---

I confirm that it works correctly when $n$ and $m$ are single digits.
If you find a proof or counterexample, please let me know.

---

(2022/04/13 edit)

A general expression was derived. I think the expression I found is that special case. The condition is that the inside of the square root is always an integer.

Here are some concrete examples.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} 
\hline
n & pattern \\ \hline
4 & \sqrt{9m^2-2m} = [3m-1;\overline{1_3,2(3m-1)}] \\ \hline
5 & \sqrt{25m^2-14m+2} = [5m-2;\overline{1_4,2(5m-2)}] \\ \hline
7 & \sqrt{169m^2-140m+29} = [13m-6;\overline{1_6,2(13m-6)}] \\ \hline
8 & \sqrt{441m^2-394m+88} = [21m-10;\overline{1_7,2(21m-10)}] \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: Just curious, how the heck did you find that pattern experimentally?

Comment: a periodic pattern in a standard continuous fraction appear for numbers which are solutions to quadratic polynomials.

Comment: @TheBestMagician
I analyzed using [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) for the sequence that appears.
Some guesses are also included.

Comment: @Oliver Diaz - he really does not mean periodic; it is more repetitive till the last value.

Comment: @Salcio: the repetitive in continuous fractions means periodic. At the end if you put things together, as in the solution below, you need to salve an appropriate quadratic equation.

Answer (score 8):

I think your claims are correct but quite needlessly complicated. The theorem at the end of this answer shows a result which is both simpler to write out and more general.

Let $(F_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be the standard Fibonacci sequence, defined by $F_0=0,F_1=1$ and $F_{n+2}=F_n+F_{n+1}$ for $n\geq 1$.

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$, and $f^n=f\circ f \circ \ldots \circ f$ ($n$ times). It is easy to check by induction that

$$
f^n(x)=\frac{\big(F_{n+1}-F_n\big)+\big(2F_n-F_{n+1}\big)x}{F_n+(F_{n+1}-F_n)x} \tag{1}
$$

Now let $a\geq 1$ be an integer. If we put $g(x)=f(\frac{1}{a+x})$,

$$
g(x)=\frac{\big(F_{n+1}-F_n\big)(x+a)+\big(2F_n-F_{n+1}\big)}{F_n(x+a)+F_{n+1}-F_n} \tag{2}
$$

The roots of $g(x)=x$ are therefore defined by the equation

$$
x^2+ax-\bigg(\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}(a-1)+2-a\bigg)=0 \tag{3}
$$

This is quadratic whose roots are $-\frac{a}{2}\pm \sqrt{\Delta}$ where

$$
\Delta = \frac{a^2}{4} + \bigg(\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}(a-1)+2-a\bigg) \tag{4}
$$

For $n\geq 3$, we have $F_{n+1}=\frac{3}{2}F_{n}+\frac{1}{2}F_{n-3}$ and hence $F_{n+1}\geq \frac{3}{2}F_{n}$. It follows from (4) that $\Delta \geq \frac{a^2}{4} + 4\bigg(\frac{3}{2}(a-1)+2-a\bigg) \gt \frac{a^2}{4}$, so that the largest root $\alpha$ of $g(x)=x$ is positive. Thus :

**Theorem.** For any $n\geq 3$ and $a\geq 2$, there is a unique positive number whose continued fraction is $[\overline{1_{n},\ a}]$. This number is

$$
\alpha = -\frac{a}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4} + \bigg(\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}(a-1)+2-a\bigg)} \tag{5}
$$

**Update.** When $a$ is of the form $a=F_n(2m+1)+1$, it is straightforward to compute that

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\Delta &=& \frac{4F_n^3m^2 + (8F_nF_{n+1} + (4F_{n}^3 - 4F_n^2))m + (4F_nF_{n+1} + (F_n^3 - 2F_n^2 + 5F_n)}{4F_n} \\ 
&=& F_n^2 m^2 + (2F_{n+1} + F_{n}^2 - 1)m + F_{n+1} + \frac{F_n^2-2F_n+5}{4} 
\end{array}
$$

So that $\Delta$ is an integer iff $F_n^2-2F_n+5$ is divisible by $4$. This is easily seen to be the case when $n\not\equiv 2$ modulo $3$.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that it is not necessary to multiply the second term of equation (4) by four.

Comment: As you pointed out, the expression I found is complicated. However, it seems to give a condition that the inside of root is an integer.

Comment: @isato Regarding the multiplication by four : fixed now, thanks. Regarding your other point, I agree that this is a part of your question that is not answered yet.

Comment: @isato I have updated my solution to answer this part of your question (please notice that my $n$ is your $n-1$).

Comment: I see, thank you. There is probably a miscalculation in the algebraic calculation, but I understand the flow. I also care about the last condition. Isn't it $ n\not\equiv 0 $? (Condition that $ F_n $ is odd)